# QR code on my phone looks different

Tags: address, qrcode, copay

I just set up a personal wallet, and the QR code on my phone, looks different from the QR code that blockchain.info shows. When I scan, the code on blockchain.info, I get the same address. I thought the QR codes were Unique.

what is going on?
This is a new wallet, and I used the copay app, to create it.

Im not sure how to get the QR code off my phone, this is why I went to blockchain.info, so I could get an address I can print. The image from blockchain.info

[image: qr]

Comment: Using HD wallets gives you access to a multitude of addresses. Each wallet could simply be generating a qr code for different addresses (both of which you own). Can't say for sure unless you share the qr codes.

Comment: Im not sure how to share the one on my phone, Thats why i went to blockchain.info in the firstplace.

Comment: QR codes can in fact differ even when they encode the same data, because they may be generated with different levels of error correction. See http://blog.qrstuff.com/2011/12/14/qr-code-error-correction for a pretty readable explanation.